# Zend Framework fetchAll

Tags: php, zend-framework, model, overriding, fetchall

Can i override fetchall method in a model? I need to check sth everytime fetchAll is called. The model extends Zend_db_table_abstract

Answer (score 9):

To override this method you would need to subclass the Zend_Db_Table_Abstract.  Like so:

```
<?php
abstract class My_Db_Table_Abstract extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    ...

    public function fetchAll($where, $order)
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Then make sure your models extend My_Db_Table_Abstract instead.  This way, you will always inherit your overridden fetchAll method.

Comment: Since you're naming it `Abstract`, you probably want it to be an `abstract class`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just define a new fetchAll() method in your model with the same construction as the Zend_db_table_abstract method (ie same input / output) then at the end of your method call the parent method:

parent::fetchAll($params)

Andrew